# Python Pyside2 QSlider через импорт класса

Tags: python, pyqt5, slider, pyside2

Есть два файла где `test.py`(основной) и (`win.py`) дизайн приложения. В основном файле `test.py` у меня вот такой код, каким образом я могу выполнить метод `test` из импортированного класса `Slider` по нажатию на слайдер

```
class Example(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

    def test(self):
        print("Клик")

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == QtGui.Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

А в **win.py**

```
class Slider(QSlider):

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(Slider, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            val = self.pixelPosToRangeValue(event.pos())
            self.setValue(val)

    def pixelPosToRangeValue(self, pos):
        opt = QStyleOptionSlider()
        self.initStyleOption(opt)
        gr = self.style().subControlRect(QStyle.CC_Slider, opt, QStyle.SC_SliderGroove, self)
        sr = self.style().subControlRect(QStyle.CC_Slider, opt, QStyle.SC_SliderHandle, self)

        if self.orientation() == Qt.Horizontal:
            sliderLength = sr.width()
            sliderMin = gr.x()
            sliderMax = gr.right() - sliderLength + 1
        else:
            sliderLength = sr.height()
            sliderMin = gr.y()
            sliderMax = gr.bottom() - sliderLength + 1;
        pr = pos - sr.center() + sr.topLeft()
        p = pr.x() if self.orientation() == Qt.Horizontal else pr.y()
        return QStyle.sliderValueFromPosition(self.minimum(), self.maximum(), p - sliderMin,
                                               sliderMax - sliderMin, opt.upsideDown)

class Ui_Form(object):


    def setupUi(self, Form):
        if not Form.objectName():
            Form.setObjectName(u"Form")
        Form.resize(286, 189)
        self.horizontalSlider = Slider(Form)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName(u"horizontalSlider")
        self.horizontalSlider.setGeometry(QRect(60, 90, 160, 22))
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(Qt.Horizontal)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Form", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я отметил строки, в которые внес изменения. Поменяйте импорты под `PySide2 !!!`

**test.py**

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets                            # PyQt5
from PyQt5.Qt import *                                                # PyQt5
# Установите импорты для                                                PySide2     !!!

from win import Slider                                                # +++


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        if not Form.objectName():
            Form.setObjectName(u"Form")
        Form.resize(286, 189)
        self.horizontalSlider = Slider(Form) 
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName(u"horizontalSlider")
        self.horizontalSlider.setGeometry(QRect(60, 90, 160, 22))
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(Qt.Horizontal)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Form", None))


class Example(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
#        ui.setupUi(self)                                                  # ---
        self.setupUi(self)                                                 # +++

        self.horizontalSlider.sliderPressed.connect(self.test)             # +++


    def test(self, val):                                                   # + val
        print(f"Клик -> {val}")                                            # + val

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
#        if e.key() == QtGui.Qt.Key_Escape:                                # ? QtGui
        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:                                # QtCore
            self.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**win.py**

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
# Установите импорты для                                                PySide2     !!!

class Slider(QSlider):
    sliderPressed = pyqtSignal(int)                                    # PyQt5
#    sliderPressed = Signal(int)                                       # PySide2     !!!

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(Slider, self).mousePressEvent(event)

        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            val = self.pixelPosToRangeValue(event.pos())
            self.setValue(val)
            self.sliderPressed.emit(val)                               # +++

    def pixelPosToRangeValue(self, pos):
        opt = QStyleOptionSlider()
        self.initStyleOption(opt)
        gr = self.style().subControlRect(QStyle.CC_Slider, opt, QStyle.SC_SliderGroove, self)
        sr = self.style().subControlRect(QStyle.CC_Slider, opt, QStyle.SC_SliderHandle, self)

        if self.orientation() == Qt.Horizontal:
            sliderLength = sr.width()
            sliderMin = gr.x()
            sliderMax = gr.right() - sliderLength + 1
        else:
            sliderLength = sr.height()
            sliderMin = gr.y()
            sliderMax = gr.bottom() - sliderLength + 1;

        pr = pos - sr.center() + sr.topLeft()
        p = pr.x() if self.orientation() == Qt.Horizontal else pr.y()

        return QStyle.sliderValueFromPosition(
            self.minimum(), 
            self.maximum(), 
            p - sliderMin,
            sliderMax - sliderMin, 
            opt.upsideDown
        )
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ты меня спас) а то я уже на грани срыва был. Огромная благодарность!!!